# Interview Q: Identify Unique Pair in Stream of data

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This was an interview question and I want to know if there is a better approach to solve this.
I have a long stream of data say, [(A, 1), (B, 2), (A, 2), (B, 1), (A, 3), (A, 4), (B, 4), ....] so on. 
Here, (A, 1) pairs with (B, 1). (A, 2) pairs with (B, 2) and so on.
In the stream (length unknown), there will be one item which won't have a pair, like (A, 3) in the above example. It is guaranteed that only 1 won't have a pair. How to determine which is that 1 item?

My approach was to have 2 Maps - 1 for A and 1 for B with Integer keys. Depending on whether it is A or B in the stream, I would check if a particular key exists in other map and if entry exists I would remove that entry, if not I would add the pair to the corresponding map it would belong to. At the end I check both the maps to see which one has a left out pair.

I feel there might be a much better approach to this. Do let me know.

```
class Pair {
    Integer value;
    String collectionName;
}

class Stream {
    public Pair getNext();
    public boolean hasNext();
}

public Pair findUniquePair(Stream s) {
    ....
}
```

I had to implement the

> findUniquePair() method

UPDATE: sorry I put in boolean as the return type earlier. Now that I remember the question fully, I did have to return a Pair. Doesn't necessarily have to be the same object though. I've updated the return type on the method accordingly.

Comment: I would sort these lexicographically and then iterate and search. Update: Ah, wait.. it is a stream? So we don't get all of the datat at once?

Comment: there will be always two pair like (A,1) with (B,2) does (C,2) also included ?

Comment: Are there really only two collection names?

Comment: Because it is stream of data I would imagine a solution without much use of data memory is preferred. Runtime is O(n) because we have to walk through each stream until done. Memory usage should be O(1) if possible. The xor answer below makes that O(1) memory.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul There are only 2 types of Pairs A's or B's.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes only 2 collections names

Comment: @latestVersion yes then try my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works only in the presence of the "only one non-paired item" guarantee: initialize an `int` result to zero, and walk the stream item-by-item. For each item `XOR` the value with the result. When you reach the end of the stream, result will be set to the unique item. You can ignore collection name, it is not necessary:

```
Stream s = ...
while (s.hasNext()) {
    Pair p = s.getNext();
    res ^= p.getValue();
}
```

The reason why this trick works is that XOR-ing an `int` two times to the same value leaves that value unchanged. The order in which you apply XORs does not matter, because all paired XORs will eventually cancel each other out.

> I remember now that I had to return a Pair for that method. It can be a new Pair object and not necessarily the same object.

To figure out what to return for the name, `"A"` or `"B"`, make a simple counter. When you see an `"A"`, add 1 to it; when you see `"B"`, subtract 1. Keep doing the same XOR for the value.

Once you reach the end of the stream, the counter would be either positive or negative (but not zero). If it is positive, we have an unpaired `"A"`; otherwise we have an unpaired `"B"`.

Comment: What if `collectionName` *is* necessary?

Comment: I don't think you can ignore the name; OP explicitly says that the unique pair in the example is `(A, 3)`. However it is easy to augment your code with a counter. Increment it on `A`, and decrement it on `B`. At the end it will be either `1` or `-1`.

Comment: There is no _collection_ of counters. There is a _single_ counter, and it doesn't compromise O(1).

Comment: @MarkRansom Why would it be necessary, if the problem could be solved without using it? Like I said in the comment above, I am not sure if this solution is better than what problem setters had in mind (it happened to me once or twice at a real interview :-)

Comment: @user58697 I figured it out after writing the first version of the comment. I thought that using a counter would result in an integer overflow, but after thinking a little I figured out that two overflows would cancel each other out, so your approach with adding and subtracting would work as well (assuming an implementation language that does not treat numeric overflows as undefined behavior).

Comment: Sorry, I see now why you state the name is not necessary - the function return is a boolean, and there's no way to return the name even if you detected it. For that matter there's no way to return the detected number either.

Comment: @MarkRansom Well, `pair.collectionName` is the name (`"A"` or `"B"` in his case). After reading user58697's comment I think I know why interviewers included it (they were looking for a solution based on addition and subtraction, with defined behavior on integer overflow).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I've updated the question. I remember now that I had to return a Pair for that method. It can be a new Pair object and not necessarily the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

Logic is :

taking Unicode code representing of char and adding one and second item as it is, and checking if the tuple is  exist or not if exist then keep that in the track list and at last just check original list with the track.

In python :

```
data=[('A', 1), ('B', 2), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('A', 3), ('A', 4), ('B', 4)]



track=[]

for i in data:
    if (chr(ord(i[0])+1),i[1]) in data:
        if (chr(ord(i[0]) + 1), i[1]) not in track:
            track.extend([i,(chr(ord(i[0])+1),i[1])])

print(list(filter(lambda x:x not in track,data)))
```

output:

```
[('A', 3)]
```